# How to clear undo history for the application through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, undo-redo

In the application, I am restricting the undo event based on keyCode and a boolean flag. I want to restrict undo only in case the boolean is true. But, once the boolean flag chages its value and undo event is fired, I am getting the output which I wanted to restrict. Is there any way that I can clear undo history stack whenever I am restricting user to do undo.

Here is sample of code:

```
    var ctrlZ = e.ctrlKey && e.which === 90 ;

    if(ctrlZ && restrictUndoFlag){

        e.preventDefault();

        //clear the undo history here

        globalConfig.restrictUndoFlag = false;
    }
```

I think the browser is maintaining the history for my application for undo and redo. Please suggest me the way that I can restrict this behavior.

Comment: @peeebeee doesn't that only apply to codemirror?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Flag rescinded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to onclick="history.clear();"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920806/is-it-possible-to-onclick-history-clear)